# WP Menu Walker - How to know total depth from inside the start_lvl() method

Tags: menus, walker

The [start_lvl()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/walker_nav_menu/start_lvl/) method allows to know the current `$depth` parameter. But, I need to output different results at level 1 if the menu has x or y total levels.

I did a `print_r()` of the `$args` array, but there isn't anything I can use to achieve the desired result:

```
<!--Custom_Menu_Walker Object
(
    [tree_type] => Array
        (
            [0] => post_type
            [1] => taxonomy
            [2] => custom
        )

    [db_fields] => Array
        (
            [parent] => menu_item_parent
            [id] => db_id
        )

    [max_pages] => 1
    [has_children] => 1
)
-->
```

The most useful thing is to know if the current level has children. And even that isn't supposed to be used in the `walker level`:

> **From the docs**: Whether the current element has children or not. To be used in start_el().

And even though it can be accessed from level, it doesn't allow me to know if any of the children have more children.

How do you suggest to approach this?